# Excel: Sum a range of cells if there is a non-zero value in another column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a spread sheet like this:

```
ID  time    Episode    mints

1   5:00PM  0   
1   6:00PM  1          10

1   6:10PM  0   
1   6:30PM  0   
2   1:00AM  0   
2   2:00AM  1          60

2   3:00AM  0   
2   1:00AM  2          30

2   1:10AM  3   
2   1:20AM  4   
2   1:30AM  0
```

I want to calculate the time difference between the row has the first non-zero value to the row hits the first 0. For example, in ID1, the duration would be 6:10PM - 6:00PM, which would be 10 minutes.

I somehow got a sense that I should use match() and index() function but after several trials, I got no luck.

Comment: question not clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

A series of nested if's or cocenates might do the trick here, if you say you'll never have more than 2-4 non-0 numbers in a row. Basically, you ask "Do I have a non-0 number? (=if(A1=0,True,False). If it's 0, you don't care, move on. (True =""). If it's not 0, look for the next number, check if that's 0. (=if(B1=0,true, false). If that's 0, great! True=(B2-A2). Otherwise, repeat, but use C1 instead of B1. Nest a few ifs, and you have a clunky, conditional, working solution.

There are better solutions out there, I just can't think of one immediately.